# Create Embedded Hypervisor from pendrive for IBM System X (x3850 M2)

Tags: vmware-esxi, ibm, hypervisor, ibm-xseries

I have an IBM x3850 M2 (7233). There is an USB port on the inside of it which - according to its manual - is for an embedded hypervisor. I plugged the an empty pendrive into the internal socket and installed a VMWare ESXi image which I downloaded from the IBM support site [from here](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/systemx/downloadFixes?parent=System%2Bx3850%2BM2&product=ibm/systemx/7233&&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=ibm_sw_hyper_799733source_vmwaresx5_32-64&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http) (requires log in, the name of the download is: `VMware vSphere Hypervisor (ESXi) 5.1 with IBM Customization VMware`). The server doesn't recognize it as an embedded hypervisor, it recognizes it as a USB storage devices.

How do I make the server to recognize it as an embedded hypervisor, so I can set the server to boot to it?